# Proving the lines $AB$ and $PQ$ are perpendicular

Tags: geometry

The points A, B, C and D, in this particular order, lie on a circle. The chords AC and BD intersect in the point P, the line through $C$ perpendicular to AC and the line through $D$ perpendicular to BD intersect in the point Q.

How do you prove that the line AB and PQ are perpendicular to one another?

NOTE: the chords do not have to be perpendicular to one another!

**Note**

The following image makes both lines evidently nontangent to the circle. OP's last drawing makes the line perpendicular to BD seem tangent. Thanks GeoGebra :).

[image]

Comment: Please add an image. "the perpendicular line" perpendicular to what and passing through what?

Comment: okay, done! @MickG

Comment: The drawing you added makes people think the chords must be perpendicular. Is that required? If not, better note it in the question (or include another drawing without this "inconveniency").

Comment: you're right, sorry for the inconvenience! I noted it in the question

Comment: Other inconvenience: seems $P$ is the center of the circle, thus seems the chords are diameters, thus the lines $QD$ and $QC$, being orthogonal to diameters, are tangent to the circle, which need not be, right?

Comment: indeed! I just uploaded a different picture

Comment: Altogether, when making a diagram of a problem, it is best to avoid anything that looks like anything it's not guaranteed to be. That is, don't draw two lines at anywhere near a right angle unless they are guaranteed to be perpendicular; don't draw chords anywhere near the center of the circle unless they're supposed to be diameters; don't draw two chords nearly the same length unless they're really equal; and so forth. Your second attempt fixed one such ambiguity but left several others.

Comment: alright, thanks guys, I'll try to fix it! I'm still in middle school, so I definitely got a lot to learn

Comment: The current version of the image is wrong $-$ the line perpendicular to $AC$ must go through $C$, not $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $PCQD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Can you figure out the solution from the figure?

[image]

Comment: The diagram looks amazing? How do you create those?

Comment: I didn't quite get it, I thought all vertices of a cyclic quadrilateral have to touch the circumference of the circle?

Comment: 1. [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) is a great tool. 2. $C$ and $D$ both lie on the circle with diameter $PQ$ because of two right angles $\angle PCQ$ and $\angle PDQ$.

Comment: oh okay thanks! But how do I mathematically prove the perpendicularity from this conclusion?

Comment: Let $\gamma = \angle DQP = \angle DCP = \angle DCA = \angle DBA$. The lines $DP$ and $DQ$ are perpendicular. If you rotate them by an angle $\gamma$, in the same direction, you get the directions of lines $QP$ and $BA$. So these two lines are perpendicular.

Comment: wouldn't you have to rotate them by an angle alpha?

Comment: Why rotation? As shown in the picture $\alpha+\beta=90^\circ$. Now what happens in $\triangle BPM$?

Comment: alpha and beta are found in the same triangle?